# Getting Assembly DeclaredProperties from External DLL

Tags: c#

I must be making this harder than it is.  I am using Assembly.LoadFile in the attempts of checking a single Property in the DLL I am loading.  The gotcha, is that the property is actually part of the DLL's base DLL (not sure if that makes a difference).  I can locate the property I am trying to retrieve in QuickView, but I have yet to get to that property from code.  I presume one of you brilliant minds can quickly show me the proper path or algorithm to get to the property I seek.

The QuickView path is:
((System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[])((System.Reflection.TypeInfo)((System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo)baseMembers[32]).PropertyType).DeclaredProperties)[0]

[image]

This is the code I have thus far, which does get me down to that property, but I cannot yet find a value for any of the properties that are built into the DLL.

```
            var loadedFile = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);

            var types = loadedFile.GetTypes();
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (!type.Name.Contains("MpIntegrator"))
                    continue;

                var baseMembers = type.BaseType.GetMembers();

                foreach (var baseMember in baseMembers)
                {
                    if (baseMember.Name != "Features")
                        continue;

                    var props = baseMember?.DeclaringType?.GetProperties();
                    var propType = (((System.Reflection.PropertyInfo) props[4]).PropertyType);
                    var decalProperties = ((System.Reflection.TypeInfo)propType).DeclaredProperties;

                    if (decalProperties != null)
                        foreach (var prop in decalProperties)
                        {
                            if (prop.Name.Contains("Registration"))
                            {
                                //This doesn't work
                                registration = prop.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
```

Does anybody have a method for retrieving the DeclaredProperties of a MemberInfo object?

Thanks.

Comment: Not quite clear what an "inherited dll" might be.  But never, never use LoadFile().  Use LoadFrom() so the runtime has a shot at resolving dependent assemblies.  LoadFile is only useful when you *don't* want that to happen, that's quite rare.

Comment: The DLL I am now doing a LoadFrom() on, references a Base DLL that contains the property I am trying to get to.

Comment: You get a type from props[4]).PropertyType. Then you use that *type* to get the fields ? Have you tried props.DeclaredProperties instead ? and what happens when you use foreach (var prop in props) ?